# Clean sqlite database, from another android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I developed an Android application that works on sqlite internal db. 
Now I want create a new android application that clean the database of my first application. 
What can I do?

Comment: Aren't Android apps sandboxed?

Comment: Try to use ContentProvider in first app, and make provider available to others app

Comment: Mike's got it.  It's the only way since one app cannot access the data of another unless the other app advertises it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the second application send a intent broadcast, after receiving the broadcast, let the first application can clear the data. But any application cannot clear another application's data, even if it is possible, it is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it if you modify the manifest of both apps to make them share the same data directory.

Add the `android:sharedUserId` property to the manifest of each app.

```
android:sharedUserId="your.shared.id"
```

If they are the same and you sign them with the same key & alias, each of the appa can use/access the others private directories.